# How can I summarize by group by in (R)?

Tags: r, group-by, summarize

I would like to summarize Votes by Party.

My table:

| State | Party | Votes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NY | RP | 80 |
| NY | DM | 20 |
| CA | RP | 30 |
| CA | DM | 70 |

Expected:

| Party | Votes |
| --- | --- |
| RP | 110 |
| DM | 90 |

This doesnt work for me:

```
data <- data %>% group_by(Party) %>% summarise(Votos)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `sum()` function within `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Party) %>% 
  summarise(Votes = sum(Votes, na.rm = TRUE))
```

```
 Party Votes
  <chr> <int>
1 DM       90
2 RP      110
```

If you want to have sorted:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Party) %>% 
  summarise(Votes = sum(Votes, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Votes))
```

```
  Party Votes
  <chr> <int>
1 RP      110
2 DM       90
```

Comment: That gives me this data frame: 1 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Votos: num 7176015

Comment: What is your dataframe named ? `df` or `data`? this must work. Please load `library(dplyr)`

Comment: yes, I dont know why doesnt work my group by.

Comment: If you have a longer pipe, maybe you have to `ungroup()` before.

Comment: Thanks! I wrote this: dplyr::summarise. And it works!